# Build android error activity manager

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity

Please help me, i try build android with eclipse on device phone warning error

```
[2013-11-10 19:04:28 - SynergyAutoparts] Android Launch!
[2013-11-10 19:04:28 - SynergyAutoparts] adb is running normally.
[2013-11-10 19:04:28 - SynergyAutoparts] Performing com.gatot.synergyautoparts.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-11-10 19:04:31 - SynergyAutoparts] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-11-10 19:04:31 - SynergyAutoparts] Starting activity com.gatot.synergyautoparts.MainActivity on device SANUGYPY5KBWOYLNVB6
[2013-11-10 19:04:32 - SynergyAutoparts] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.gatot.synergyautoparts/.MainActivity }
[2013-11-10 19:04:32 - SynergyAutoparts] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

thk

Comment: Before installation android will check if the application package already present or not. If the previous installation and the new installation is same means there in so change happened in the code or installation android wont proceed the installation. Instead the running activity will bring on top.

Comment: installation on the same device and existing applications....

Answer (score 0):

Just kill currently working process on your AVD and try to this again. AVD relaunch can help as well.